# Setting up CORS for a specific method and url

Tags: authentication, http, cors

First of all, apologies if you think this should be on stackoverflow.com - it seemed more suitable for this site but it's a bit borderline.

We have a partner site, i'll call it `http://bob.com`.  For the sake of argument, my site is called `http://alice.com`.  I have full control over `alice.com`, but no control over `bob.com`.  I can, however, ask `bob.com` to make changes to their site, although they are reluctant to do so.  The situation is that a change request by me is much more likely to be implemented if it is A) small & B) very clearly defined.  Because I myself have a login to bob.com, i can see how their requests, paths, params, etc are structured.

So, that's the background.  The problem i want to solve is this:  Let's say that we have a user, Jimmy, of `alice.com`.  In our alice.com database i of course have Jimmy's username and password (whether i encrypt them or not is not relevant here).  Jimmy also has a login on `bob.com`, and **in my `alice.com` database I also have his `bob.com` username and password**.

I want to have a button on my `alice.com` site which logs Jimmy into `bob.com`.  In a simple world, this button would submit a form to the `bob.com` login url, passing Jimmy's username and password in the appropriately named parameters.  `bob.com` would accept this request, and Jimmy would now be logged into `bob.com`.

What's stopping this from happening is that `bob.com` has a CSRF (cross site request forgery) protection system using an authentication token which is tied to a cookie.  I could **try** to get around this by making an ajax request to the login page, reading the auth token from the response, and then passing this through again with the form request.  However there are two problems with this:

1) If i try to make the ajax request, the request is denied because the response doesn't have the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://alice.com", which i believe is necessary to make the ajax request work - from the CORS section here http://jquery-howto.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

2) Even if I manage to get the auth token with ajax (ie get past the CORS stuff) then i'm not sure if the request will work because it's coming from a different domain.  I can manage this in CURL, successfully logging in from my command line by saving the cookie and passing it through in the subsequent request, but i think the rules for the browser are different and i can't quite get my head around it.

So, (sorry this has dragged on a bit), my question is:

What is the simplest change i can ask `bob.com` to make to their site, to allow someone on `alice.com` to be logged into `bob.com`, if `alice.com` knows their `bob.com` username and password?

Am i on the right track with the Ajax & CORS thing?  If so, then would i need to ask them to set access control for our site, just for the login submission?

Comment: This is the wrong approach entirely. If the other site wants people to be able to use their logins to sign into other sites (e.g. Login with Facebook, Google+, etc) then they will implement OAuth2.

Comment: Hi Michael.  This isn't about implementing a general open-auth system, it's really just about making a small change to allow one of their partners (ie us) to take people past the login screen.